# Using parameter as column name in Postgres function

Tags: postgresql, function, parameters

I have a Postgres table bearing the following form

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."days" 
(
 "id" integer NOT NULL,
 "day" character varying(9) NOT NULL,
 "visits" bigint[] NOT NULL,
 "passes" bigint[] NOT NULL
);
```

I would like to write a function that allows me to return the `visits` or the `passees` column as its result for a specified `id`.  My first attempt goes as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION day_entries(INT,TEXT) RETURNS BIGINT[] LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT $2 FROM days WHERE id = $1;'
```

which fails with an error along the lines of

> return type mismatch in function declared to return bigint[]
>   DETAIL: Actual return type is text.

If I put in `visits` in place of the `$2` things work just as expected.  It would make little sense to define several functions to match different columns from the `days` table.  Is there a way to pass the actual column name as a parameter while still keeping Postgres happy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use parameters as identifiers (=column name), you need dynamic SQL for that. And that requires PL/pgSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION day_entries(p_id int, p_column text) 
  RETURNS BIGINT[] 
AS
$$
declare 
  l_result bigint[];
begin
  execute format('SELECT %I FROM days WHERE id = $1', p_column) 
     using p_id
     into l_result;
  return l_result;
end;     
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[format()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) properly deals with identifiers when building dynamic SQL. The `$1` is a parameter placeholder and the value for that is passed with the `using p_id` clause of the `execute` statement.